# best way to compare different objects in powershell

Tags: powershell

Not sure if this is even possible, but I'm trying to compare properties of an ADgroup object and a PSCustomObject object. We're in the middle of a user audit which requires validating a list of active employees against our active AD user accounts along with their AD group memberships. Here's a basic breakdown of what I have so far:

(we're defining two separate search paths because we have groups in different OUs)

- $mainGroups = get-adgroup -filter * -searchbase 'OU_here'
- $subGroups = get-adgroup filter * -searchbase 'Different_OU_here'

List of usernames from HR system

- $sourceUsers = get-content -path 'c:\temp\users.txt'

List of usernames from AD

- $ADUserName = get-aduser -filter * -searchbase 'User_OU' -searchscope subtree | select -expandproperty SamAccountName

Empty array to store custom object/properties

- $userObjEQ = @()

Compare HR to AD

- $compareResults = compare-object -referenceobject $sourceUsers -differenceObject $ADUserName
- Find group memberships of all matching users, create custom object, etc

  ```
  foreach ($result in $compareResults) {
      if ($result.SideIndicator -eq '==') {
          $groupMem = get-adprincipalgroupmembership -identity $result.InputObject
      }
      $userObjEQ += [pscustomobject] @{
      'UserName' = $result.InputObject
      'Groups' = $groupMem.Name
      }
  }
  ```

From this point on, I want to compare every group from each matching user to the group name from the $mainGroups to see if there's a match. If there isn't then compare it to the $subGroups group names. If there's a match do nothing, if there's a mismatch, output the username along with any mismatched group names. Just not sure how best to compare these objects. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: So you have a List of Users. 
You want to get the ADGroups each user is in?

Comment: @ArcSet No sorry, I have a list of active users from our HR dept. I've stored the usernames from that list into the sourceUsers variable. Then I grabbed a list of usernames from active AD users. I compare both list and extract only the usernames that match.

What I did from there is grabbed a list of all groups that each matching user belongs to. 

What I want to do now is figure out how to compare each matching user's group to the groups found in the $mainGroups and $subGroups OU. Sorry if I'm not explaining it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your groups are arrays, then use the -contains operator -- if they're not, make them arrays:

```
foreach ($u in $users) {
   foreach ($groupdn in $u.memberof) {
      if ($mainGroups -contains $ug -or $subGroups -contains $ug) {
         ## do something when the users' group exists in the checked sub-groups
      }
   }
}
```

...this assumes the $maingroups array is an array of group DNs...

Comment: nvm, i think i get what you're doing there. I modified the logic to match my current script and it seems to be doing what I want, so I will accept this as the answer.